# nginx redirect multiple servers to SSL

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have this code. I just want each of the server_name in the list to redirect to its own name https. But, if I do http://beta.example.com, it redirects to https://api.example.com (or whatever the first item in the list is)

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    api.example.com beta.example.com apibeta.example.com nodebeta.example.com app.example.com;
    return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to use the `$host` variable instead:

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    api.example.com beta.example.com apibeta.example.com nodebeta.example.com app.example.com;
    return         301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: yes we just figured that out. although I had read that you ought to use your own variables if possible i.e. $server_name, not $host, but $server_name seems not to work for some reason

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to redirect all domains to HTTPS, you might use a wildcard server name: `server_name _;`.

Comment: I could imagine that `$server_name` is derived based on the configuration, while `$host` is the value specified with the `Host:` header during a particular request.

Comment: This does not work for me if the address is given with the scheme http in front, so beta.example.com redirects correctly, but http://beta.example.com redirects to https://api.example.com. Is that expected behavior?